# Opencl global variable has different value in threads, OpenCL KERNEL

Tags: c, global-variables, opencl

So I am dealing with the following situation. I want all my threads to do a loop until none of them reaches a certain "if", so I use a global variable that stores 0 and when the if statement is reached that variable becomes 1.

The problem is that at the end of the loop I do a barrier to synchronize all the threads( in my case I just have 4) and only does that reached the if have the value of the global variable 1, the others have it 0.

How can that be? How can a global variable have different values in different threads?

Comment: a thread should check the global variable after the barrier, not before it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the global variable is set as some buffer and caches, one of you thread write this variable to 1 but not write through to the physical memory but in the cacheline. The other threads didn't get the updated value in such cases.